# fragment to another fragment like a dialog

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to make a simple thing, but I didn't succeed to do it. I have a viewpager with five fragments and I just want that when I click on a button which is on a fragment, another fragment appears and I want to be able to handle the transition between these two fragments.

So I have my fragments and I try to put them in another viewpager so I could interact with the other fragment, but I think there is more simple and I didn't succeed to do it. I discovered dialogs, I think that what I want to do is close to that but that not exactly that because I want that my fragment takes all the screen. To be clear, I want to recreate the fragment that appears when you want to add friends on the snapchat app.

If you could help me, I would be very grateful.

Comment: You can just [use FragmentManager and transition to your new fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/transactions), is there any issue with that?

Comment: thanks for your response, i try to use : getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, BlankFragment.class, null);
but nothing is happening, i just want to show this fragment

Comment: You didn't commit the transaction. Please read the docs again carefully.

Comment: thanks a lot, sorry that i bother you for that.